# Jenkins `Make gradlew executable` option do not make `gradelw executable

Tags: linux, jenkins, gradle, file-permissions, gradlew

I have Jenkins setup on linux machine (CentOS) and I tried to build Gradle based project on the master host. My project use `Stash` Git-based repository as SCM.

In the Jenkins build job I have enabled `Clean before checkout` option. And I see that `gradlew` script is checkouted without executable permissions. So, I set `Make gradlew executable` checkbox for the task. But I still see issue:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/project/dir/gradlew" (in directory "/project/dir/"): error=13, Permission denied
```

I checked `gradlew` permissions and there is no executable on for the file.

Does anyone know how to debug/setup it?

Now, I have to use addetional build step `execute shell script` to set executable permissions for `gradlew`.

*Note 1*: I use `Use Gradle Wrapper` build option instead of `Invoke Gradle` because of some suggestions I found in the Internet.

*Note 2*: I found [make gradlew script executable](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14780) issue and checked that my Jenkins build should contain this fix. I use Jenkins build 1.581

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Lets assume the file script.sh needs to have the executable bit set. Use the `command git ls-tree` to inspect the file permissions:

```
C:\views\myproject>git ls-tree HEAD
100644 blob 55c0287d4ef21f15b97eb1f107451b88b479bffe    script.sh
```

As you can see the file has 644 permission (ignoring the 100). We would like to change it to 755:

```
C:\views\myproject>git update-index --chmod=+x script.sh
C:\views\myproject>git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   script.sh
#
```

The file is now staged. Note that the file contents is not changed, only the meta data. We must commit the file so save the change:

```
C:\views\myproject>git commit -m "Changing file permissions"
[master 77b171e] Changing file permissions
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 mode change 100644 => 100755 script.sh
```

Running `git ls-tree` again to see the change:

```
C:\views\myproject>git ls-tree HEAD
100755 blob 55c0287d4ef21f15b97eb1f107451b88b479bffe    script.sh
```

[Source](http://blog.lesc.se/2011/11/how-to-change-file-premissions-in-git.html)